# flipster.js - onItemSwitch seems to fire when I click on current item

Tags: jquery, jquery-flipster

I am using the jQuery 'plugin' flipster for a cloverflow-like animation. I  want to trigger a jQuery event (change classes of a text div "#content_stage", which is outside flipster) when the items change – and only when they change. This container ("#content_stage") can load different content for each slide, but is only be visible after a "show content" click and should always become hidden (hence the changed class) when the flipster carousel is moving to a different slide.

The event handler onItemSwitch however seems to fire whenever I click on any of the items – even on the current item (which (of course) does not initiate an actual change). This is probably as it is because the "onItemSwitch" is triggered by "function center()" which is again seems to be triggered by a click on **any** item. Is there a way to really only focus on the actual "change" event?

ps: I am basically using the exact code as on this demo page:
http://a.drien.com/jquery-flipster/

Inside jQuery.flipster.js my settings currently look like this:

```
onItemSwitch: function(currentItem, previousItem){

    if( jQuery( "#content_stage" ).hasClass("expanded")) {
        jQuery( "#content_stage" ).removeClass( "expanded" );
        jQuery( "#content_stage" ).addClass( "hidden" );
        alert("alert");
    }
},
```

UPDATE: see answer below…

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this work:

```
onItemSwitch: (currentItem, previousItem) => {
  $(previousItem).removeClass("expanded");
  $(currentItem).addClass("expanded");
},
```

!?

What's `$('#content_stage')`? Why are you adding class `hidden` to it?
Are all ids unique in your markup?

Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the relevant markup, styling and external resources, it's technically impossible to figure out what your code does (other than you're adding/removing some classes to an element with `id="content_stage"`, which could do nothing or a lot, but we can't really tell from what you've shown so far...)

It looks like flipster only fires the `onItemSwitch` when the item actually switched. To check, I made this demo. As you can see, no matter what happens, it only fires when the item did change:

```js
function getIndex(el) {
  return Array.from(el.parentNode.children).indexOf(el)
}
$('.flipster').flipster({
  onItemSwitch: (current,prev) => {
    console.log('switched from ',getIndex(prev),' to ',getIndex(current)
   )
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://brokensquare.com/Code/jquery-flipster/dist/jquery.flipster.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://brokensquare.com/Code/jquery-flipster/demo/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://brokensquare.com/Code/jquery-flipster/dist/jquery.flipster.min.js"></script>

<div class="flipster">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250"></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250"></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250"></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250"></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250"></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x250"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I am trying to add/remove a class to/from a div that is outside flipster to show/hide content for each slide. I edited my original post…

Comment: `onItemSwitch` only fires when the item has switched. You probably have some `click` event bound to your markup which you haven't shown here. I added a demo clearly showing that function is **only** fired when flipster changes, no matter how many times you click on current element. If you need more help, update the question with **all relevant code**.

Answer (score 0):

I found it: around line 312 in jquery.flipster.js the code looked like this:

```
// Navigate directly to an item by clicking
    _flipItems.on("click", function(e) {
        if ( !$(this).hasClass("flip-current") ) { e.preventDefault(); }
        jump(_flipItems.index(this));
    });
```

So the "jump" was initiated after any click – even after a click on the current item. instead it should be like this to prevent triggering the onItemSwitch event on a click on the current item:

```
// Navigate directly to an item by clicking
    _flipItems.on("click", function(e) {
        if ( !$(this).hasClass("flip-current") ) { e.preventDefault(); }
        if ( !$(this).hasClass("flip-current") ) { jump(_flipItems.index(this)); }
    });
```

Comment: Perhaps you're using a bugged version. What you're describing doesn't happen in the demo I made and I took the resource links from their demo page. It's also possible `_flipItems` doesn't actually do anything if the `index` hasn't changed. As a rule of thumb, changing things inside libs is to be avoided. If you want a change in a lib you're better forking it (and submitting a pull-request, if it's a bug). This way you make sure the author looks at your change and has a chance to tell you what you're breaking (if).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't think I'm using a bugged version since I'm using the exact code from  http://a.drien.com/jquery-flipster/ –– well of course this might be buggy anyways…:/